# Rails - Building a JSON object with multiple items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

currently I am creating a JSON object as follows:

```
@comments = Array.new

comments.collect do |comment|
  @comments << {
    :id => comment.id,
    :content => html_format(comment.content),
    :created_at => comment.created_at
  }
end

@comments.to_json
```

And this returns something like this:

```
[{"created_at":"2011-03-02T09:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>Random.......</p>","id":734}, {"created_at":"2011-03-02T09:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>asdasd.......</p>","id":714}, {"created_at":"2011-03-01T09:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>Random.......</p>","id":134}, {"created_at":"2011-03-01T02:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>dasdasdasdasd.......</p>","id":3124}]
```

Problem here is that I need to include a few other items that aren't arrays. What I would like is the JSON object to look something like this:

```
[comments: {"created_at":"2011-03-02T09:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>Random.......</p>","id":734}, {"created_at":"2011-03-02T09:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>asdasd.......</p>","id":714}, {"created_at":"2011-03-01T09:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>Random.......</p>","id":134}, {"created_at":"2011-03-01T02:17:27-08:00","content":"<p>dasdasdasdasd.......</p>","id":3124}, last_load: "123123123123", last_view: "zxczcxzxczxc"]
```

Any ideas on how I can take what I have above, and expand it to pass additional items other than the comments array?

Thank you!

Comment: I would keep my @comment Array and add whatever I need inside. Then call to_json.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add your list to a hash, and then call `to_json` on the hash.

```
> a = [1,2,3]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
> h = {:comments => a, :foo => "bar"}
 => {:foo=>"bar", :comments=>[1, 2, 3]} 
> h.to_json
 => "{\"foo\":\"bar\",\"comments\":[1,2,3]}"
```